# Unity C# Shop Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, menu

[image]Hey guys I have been building a shop menu that is activated when the button is pressed. I have four buttons in the menu that correspond to several buy able items in a grid. The buttons and text and Image attached are inside a GameObject. I'm trying to switch between menus with SetActive. I've successfully used SetActive to open and close the menu but when I try with the other portions they stay inactive regardless. Even when the button supposedly activating is pressed. The picture I uploaded shows the hierarchy of the shop. The buttons are under ShopSelection and the actual menu is Under Shop

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static UIManager instance;
    public  static UIManager Instance;
    public GameObject shopMenu, motherShips, resources, fleets, research;
    bool menuIsOpen = false;
    bool motherShipOpen = false;
    bool resourcesOpen = false;
    bool fleetOpen = false;
    public Button shop, motherShipButton, resourceButton, fleetButton, exitButton; 

    void Start () {
        shopMenu.SetActive(false);
        //Open Shop Menu
        Button btn = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        //Open Motherships portion of shop
        Button btn1 = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn1.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick3);
        //Open resources portion of shop
        Button btn2 = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn2.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick4);
        //Open fleet portion of shop
        Button btn3 = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn3.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick5);
        //Open Research portion of shop
        Button btn4 = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn4.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick6);
        //Exit Menu
        Button bttn = exitButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        bttn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick2);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        shopMenu.SetActive(true);
        menuIsOpen = true;
        motherShips.SetActive(true);
    }
    void TaskOnClick2()
    {
        if (menuIsOpen == true)
        {
            shopMenu.SetActive(false);
            menuIsOpen = false;
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick3()
    {
        if(menuIsOpen == true)
        {
            //Open Motherships Shop
            motherShips.SetActive(true);
            resources.SetActive(false);
            fleets.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick4()
    {
        if (menuIsOpen == true)
        {
            //Open resources Shop
            motherShips.SetActive(false);
            resources.SetActive(true);
            fleets.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick5()
    {
        if(menuIsOpen == true)
        {
            //Open Fleet Shop
            motherShips.SetActive(false);
            resources.SetActive(false);
            fleets.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick6()
    {
        if (menuIsOpen == true)
        {
            //Open Research Page
            motherShips.SetActive(false);
            resources.SetActive(false);
            fleets.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the hierarchy of your menu?

Comment: @derHugo added a picture with a description of what's what, thanks

Comment: @derHugo It's nothing wrong with the hierarchy. If I personally enable the gameobjects they show up. They just don't activate with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added all callbacks allways to the `shop` button e.g.

```
Button btn2 = shop.GetComponent<Button>();
btn2.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick4);
```

not to the supposed buttons `motherShipButton, resourceButton, fleetButton`

---

Note that you don't have to call `GetComponent` again if you declare the variable as `Button` it will automatically reference the `Button` component of the drag&dropped GameObject in the Inspector so instead it should simply be

```
shop.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);

//Open Motherships portion of shop
motherShipButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick3);

//Open resources portion of shop
resourcesButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick4);

//Open fleet portion of shop
fleetButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick5);

//Open Research portion of shop
// Whatever button this belongs to
???.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick6);

//Exit Menu
exitButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick2);
```

Now also name the methods accordingly e.g. `OpenMenu`, `CloseMenu` etc. that would make it a lot easier for you and everyone else to understand the code.

---

I also doubt that you need the check for `if(menuIsOpen)`. Since the other GameObjects are children of the menu anyway they will simply stay invisible even if `SetActive` was called. Instead I would make sure that only one panel is active by using a method with e.g. an enum instead like

```
enum MenuPanel
{
    MotherShips,
    Resources,
    Fleets,
    Research
}

private void ShowPanel(MenuPanel panel)
{
    // First disable all
    motherShips.SetActive(false);
    fleets.SetActive(false);
    resources.SetActive(false);

    // Than only activate according panel
    switch(panel)
    {
        case MenuPanel.MotherShips:
            motherShips.SetActive(true);
            break;

        case MenuPanel.Reaources:
            resources.SetActive(true);
            break;

        case MenuPanel.Fleets:
            fleets.SetActive(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

And than I would still use dedicated methods for each panel like e.g.

```
void Start()
{
    //...
    motherShipButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowMotherShips);
    //...
}

private void ShowMotherShips()
{
    ShowPanel(MenuPanel.MotherShips);
}
```

you could do it also directly as lambda expression

```
void Start()
{
    //...
    motherShipButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        ShowPanel(MenuPanel.MotherShips);
    });
    //...
}
```

I usually try to avoid it since 1. you can not reuse this expression but you might want to call it from else where as well and 2. you will not be able to use `RemoveListener` to eventually get rid of that call.

Comment: I did not notice I did that. I must have duplicated the buttons to save time and not changed the shop to the rest of the buttons. I feel stupid. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.